# slapd command on MacOS

Tags: macos, ldap, openldap

I have the following commands on MacOS

```
$ sl

slapacl     slapadd     slapauth    slapcat     slapconfig  slapdn 
slapindex   slappasswd  slapschema  slaptest    sleep       slogin
```

I am following this tutorial on running an ldap server on MacOS:

http://krypted.com/mac-security/starting-openldap-on-mac-os-x-client/

seems strange that I don't have a `slapd` command - anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since slapd is almost never run "by hand", it's not in one of the binaries directories that're in the default PATH. Instead, it's in /usr/libexec, which is the usual place for things that're run automatically rather than manually. So run it with `sudo /usr/libexec/slapd` instead of just as `slapd`. (BTW, the `sudo` is needed so it can allocate low-numbererd TCP ports, and get full access to its database).